# If $a_{n}<a_{n+1}<b_{n+1}<b_{n}$ for all positive integers $n$. Prove that $a_{n}<3$ for all positive integers $n$. Need help with last part of proof.

Tags: inequality

Source: Numbers and Functions by R. P. Burn. Chapter: 2 Question: 38

---

$a_{n}=(1+1/n)^{n}$ and $b_{n}=(1+1/n)^{n+1}$.

I've managed to prove $b_{5}=(6/5)^{6}<3 \Rightarrow b_{n}<3$ for all $n$ such that $n>5$. Which implies $a_{n}<3$ for all $n$ such that $n>5$.

After this point I can't figure out how to prove that it holds for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Well, you have proved the property for all integers safe a finite number ($1, 2, 3, 4, 5$), so you can just check out that it remains true for those five integers

Comment: Didn't even think of that. (*facepalm*) Many thanks @DesideriusSeverus.